# phonegap doesn't connect with xampp server on localhost

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cordova, phonegap-build

I have a PhoneGap project on my windows 7 PC. I have installed the PhoneGap developer app on my PC which connects through server address: http://192.168.1.16:3000.

When I load the project on the PhoneGap developer app, everything works fine. The problem is that I have a database which is saved locally on my PC (localhost) and I access it through XAMPP. When I setup the XAMPP server I can not access the database and when I run the project it's showing me an error.

If I connect an online database on a server it works. I mean it's working with an online database but not working on localhost.

Can anyone help me how to access my database on localhost server.

```
var url = "http://localhost:81/myapp/auth.php";
```

[image]

And if i run open this link on above image result here:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aImO7.png)

Comment: The 500 error you receive from PHP should give you some important information about exactly why the DB connection is failing. Check the logs.

Comment: How did you solve this issue please, facing same thing

Answer (score 1):

Your app is running on the Phone and interprets `localhost` as its own host.

Try to use the IP you get from your Router of your PC smth. like `192.168.x.x` or so.

Also be aware that direct connections to your PC-Database may be blocked because of the `listen` config of your MySQL Server